# New line character between & and amp

Tags: php, regex, xml

I have an xml string which has some characters like &amp, &gt, &lt.Now whenever I tried to  use simplexml_load_string to convert it to SimpleXML, it returns bool(false). I checked in xml string and found that everything is fine except there is newline character in between '&' and 'amp' and similar other characters. I validated same from [xml validator](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/). It throws error : The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

So, I would like to know if there is any tool/api/way to fix it or should I use simple str_replace() to do job.

Thanks

Comment: The best way to fix broken XML is always to fix the software that created it. Otherwise, the rule to remember is: if it's not XML, use non-XML tools to repair it.

Comment: If you just need to remove whitespace between `&` and entity names, use `preg_replace('~&\s+(#\d+;|(?:[gl]t|a(?:mp|pos)|quot);)~', '&$1', $s)` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WfOcA3/1)). Manually defined entity names should be added as alternatives to the `(...|...)` group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML file should not have such issues in the first place, the **real fix** is *to eliminate the source of the issue* by fixing the code that produced these whitespaces in wrong places.

As a *quick hotfix*, you can use a regex that will find `&` followed with 1 or more whitespaces and then the entity names. Note that the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/WfOcA3/1) like

```
preg_replace('~&\s+(#\d+;|(?:[gl]t|a(?:mp|pos)|quot);)~', '&$1', $s)
```

will only deal with the numeric and predefined entities, all manually defined entities will have to be added to the `(#\d+;|(?:[gl]t|a(?:mp|pos)|quot);)` group as alternatives.

**Pattern details**:

- `&` - an ampersand
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(#\d+;|(?:[gl]t|a(?:mp|pos)|quot);)` - Group 1 matching

  - `#\d+;`  - `#`, 1+ digits, `;`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?:[gl]t|a(?:mp|pos)|quot);` - `gt`, `lt`, `amp`, `apos` or `quot` followed with `;` (= `(?:gt;|amp;|apos;|quot;)`).

Comment: thanks @Wiktor . Actually xml file is old and generated by legacy software.